# Handling of ENTER induced Submit

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have a form:

```
<form class="form-inline" {{action "doSomething" on="submit"}}>
    <form-field/>
    <form-field/>
    <form-field/>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" {{bind-attr disabled=disableSubmit}}>Reset Password</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="cancel" {{action "cancel" on="click"}}>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

And I want the `doSomething` method of the controller to be called when a user presses enter somewhere in the form (or clicks the submit button). This worked as expected until I introduced the functionality of "disabling" the submit button if certain form-field prerequisites hadn't been met. In these situations it executes the `cancel` method on the controller rather inexplicably.

Can someone help?

~~~

p.s. for the Bootstrap/JS/HTML community ... the `{{something}}` tagging is Ember based. Hopefully this doesn't put you off the scent too much as it's more of a consideration in the solution that the problem (I think).

Answer (score 1):

You can trap the event *keyDown* in your view and get the keycode of the event and compare with the *enter* keycode 13

In the view you should implement something like this code

```
keyDown: function(e) {
  if (e.keycode == 13 && this.get('controller.disableSubmit'))){
     e.preventDefault(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: It turns out the problem is stemming from the fact that I started using `Components` which receive the submit event on a carriage return (unlike in a view or handlebars template). Prior I had just used Views and my `on="submit"` statement was good enough to trap this action. I'll write up an answer soon. Regardless thanks for your help.